# I want to Play Video(show image if video is not there) Like Instagram?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, instagram

I want to play video in UITableViewCell Like Instagram.If there no video then it must show image same as Instagram functionality. But I don't have any idea how to do it.

I Download AWEasyVideoPlayer but it won't help me,

Please help me with that
or share some demos so i can get idea about this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have done this functionality using this code.

```
if (videoavailable) {

        cell.Videoplayview.hidden=YES;
          [cell.ImageUploadedimageview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[allpostdataarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"post_image"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];


    }else{

        cell.Videoplayview.hidden=NO;

               NSString *path = [[allpostdataarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"post_video"];
        NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
        moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, cell.ImageUploadedimageview.frame.size.width , cell.ImageUploadedimageview.frame.size.height)];

        [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        [moviePlayer play];
         [cell.Videoplayview addSubview:moviePlayer.view];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did try something, we could guide you in the right direction or help you with some struggles. Because you haven't posted any code, here is a tutorial on an Instagram-like application from beginning. It's a little outdated but it guided me in the right direction, hope it helps you too.

> https://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12

Ray Wenderlich is famous for very good tutorials in Objective-C and Swift.